# OpenCart:Add the E-Mail Address on the Contact Us page

Tags: php, opencart

I need to display my client's email address on the Contact Us page. How can I do this? Is there any `vqmod` plugin or any other solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more information on the problem?

Comment: @dyoverdx there is no option to display email address on contact us page in `opencart`. i need display email address on contact us page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for my question.

I need to edit this file:

```
...../catalog/view/theme/YOUR_THEME/template/information/contact.tpl
```

**Find**

```
  <div style="float: right; display: inline-block; width: 50%;">
    <?php if ($telephone) { ?>
    <b><?php echo $text_telephone; ?></b><br />
    <?php echo $telephone; ?><br />
    <br />
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($fax) { ?>
    <b><?php echo $text_fax; ?></b><br />
    <?php echo $fax; ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

**Change To**

```
          <div style="float: right; display: inline-block; width: 50%;">
            <?php if ($telephone) { ?>
            <b><?php echo $text_telephone; ?></b><br />
            <?php echo $telephone; ?><br />
            <br />
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($fax) { ?>
            <b><?php echo $text_fax; ?></b><br />
            <?php echo $fax; ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <br />
<b>Email:</b><br />
            EMAIL@YOURSITE.com<br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

work just fine.

Comment: Would it not be better to use the echo of the stored email address you place in the admin panel. OC gives store owners an option to add their store email address, you could just echo this on the page, that way, updating the admin, would update the page rather than hardcoded - must templates do this...

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid displaying stored email address which place in the admin panel in contact us page is welcome to spammers, hackers.

Comment: fair point but there are ways. "cs@store.com" and coat it with JavaScript, scramblers and png images. You can still then use the string.

Answer (score 2):

Having just come here looking for the same answer and finding it elsewhere i thought i;d update this thread as it comes high up Google when searching for this topic.

In the file mentioned above `../catalog/view/theme/YOUR_THEME/template/information/contact.tpl` do the following.

Add `<?php echo $this->config->get('config_email'); ?>` where you'd like the email to appear. This grabs the email from the admin settings page.